# Как инициализировать си строку в конструкторе

Tags: c++, ооп

Как правильно сделать инициализацию си строки? А то пишет тип `char*` нельзя присвоить `char[20]`

```
struct Data
{
    char FirmName[20];
    char OwnerName[20];
    int PhoneNum;
    char adress[20];
    char occupation[20];

public:
    Data(char FirmName[20],
         char OwnerName[20],
         int PhoneNum, 
         char adress[20], 
         char occupation[20]) 
        :   FirmName(FirmName), 
            OwnerName(OwnerName), 
            PhoneNum(PhoneNum), 
            adress(adress), 
            occupation(occupation)
    {}
};
```

Comment: В теле конструктора использовать `strcpy` или там `strcpy_s`.

Comment: Используйте `std::string`. Зачем эти сишные строки?

Comment: @alexolut мне его потом в бинарный файл сохранять

Comment: Разве же это проблема? `data()` + `size()` и точно так же сохранится как и сишная строка через [`write`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/).

Comment: @Sneiksus, Вам не нужно явно указывать модификатор доступа public - в структурах он используется по-умолчанию (к Вашему вопросу не относится, просто уточняю).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо либо убрать признак указателя (`char fieldName[20];`), либо убрать размер (`char *fieldName;`) и выделять память в конструкторе и освобождать ее в деструкторе. *Это различные подходы со своими особенностями и ограничениями, в которых так же стоит разобраться.*

В обоих случаях стоит поэлементно скопировать строку, которая передается в качестве аргумента. Как уже подсказали в комментариях, это делается с помощью функции [std::strcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy).